Stuck while solving a Fredholm integral equation using the collocation method
I'm following an example on getting an approximate solution, via de collocation method, to the Fredholm equation:
$$\psi(x)=x^4+\frac{1}{10}\int_{0}^{1}{e^{xt}\psi(t)dt}$$
The following 5-term approximation function for the kernel is used:
$$e^{xt}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{m!}x^mt^m}\approx 1+xt+\frac{x^2t^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3t^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4t^4}{4!}$$
The example affirms that "all eigenvalues for the (now approximated) kernel are real and positive, the smallest of which is $\lambda_1\approx 0.739241$."...
My question is: how is it so?  How can I find those eigenvalues?  A hint or a reference to an example (which I have tried hard to find with no avail) is greatly appreciated !
(The rest of the example and how to approximate the solution is all good.  I just have that piece missing!)
Thanks!
Diego Velez
